# DeprecationWarning: numpy.core.umath_tests

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run this python script below:

`import pandas as pd`
`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`
`from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier`
`from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score`
`from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`

It gives me the error below.

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "C:\Users\Dipali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\weight_boosting.py",
>   line 29     from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
>   DeprecationWarning: numpy.core.umath_tests is an internal NumPy module
>   and should not be imported. It will be removed in a future NumPy
>   release.

What I need to do?

Comment: is sklearn the the latest version?

Comment: >>> print (sklearn.__version__)
0.19.2

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. Your code will be working. 
sklearn developers (package from which the warning is issued) will need to fix the warning for the next versions.

Comment: it'a known issue, Sklearn dev have warn numpy guys and the have put a deprecation warning in place to let sklearn get their latest version out wich will no longer use this core component.

Answer (score 6):

You can ignore warning following ways like below

Example1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Example2:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Example 3:

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

Comment: I tried Example 2 & 3, and both didn't solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so this is a deprecation warning on Python 3.x. 
Since, this is warning your code will run fine. ***It is not an error*** (When the code stops running by graceful degradation).

The solution to remove this error is as follow:

1. As I can see you have Scikit-Learn version `0.19.2` installed you need to get the latest version. To do so enter the following command 
    `pip3 install --force-reinstall scikit-learn==0.20rc1` 
    This will install the latest versions of scikit-learn, scipy and numpy. Your deprecation warnings will now not exist.
2. Although you'll next get a new warning. This time regarding the file in the scikit-learn library called cloudpickle `\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py`. 
    To overcome this warning you got to edit the code which python shows us. 
    Just do a `sudo idle3` onto the file and edit the lines which says : 
    `import imp` 
    `from imp import find_module` 
   to
    `import importlib` 
    Next go to the funtion `find_module` and change the line 
    `file, path, description = find_module(path)` 
   to
    `file, path, description = importlib.utils.find_spec(path)`.

This must solve the deprecation warnings in the scikit-learn libraries.